# How to display the new UITableView frame?

Tags: ios

If I change the frame of a UITableView when a row is deleted, for example here:

```
tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:
{
    [tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(tableView.frame.origin.x, tableView.frame.origin.y, tableView.frame.size.width, tableView.frame.size.height + 40]
}
```

I don't see any change in the table layout. Do I need to refresh the view, in order to display the table with the new frame?

thanks

Comment: reload tableView and also delete row from `[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];`

Comment: Have you tried using animations? `[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            table.frame = frame;
        }];`

Comment: @patrick u have to give response user to give answer of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you also need to update the `tableView.contentSize = tableView.frame`

else use the

```
[tableView setNeedsLayout];
[tableView setNeedsDisplay];
```

methods to redraw the tableView

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(tableView.frame.origin.x, tableView.frame.origin.y, tableView.frame.size.width, tableView.frame.size.height + 40];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to delete the row.

```
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
numberofRowsinTable--;
```

After that,

```
[tableview reloadData];
```

Also you need to reduce and return the number of rows of the table in

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return numberofRowsinTable;
}
```